# User re-appears in Universal Security Group several days after being removed

Tags: active-directory, entra-domain-services

Where I work we have one group whereby I've removed the user from the "members" list from one of our DC's, DC03 and then checked on the other two DC's DC01 and DC02 and can confirm that the changes are replicated, USN's increased.

What's odd is that after a couple of days in this case about a week went past the second time around, the user object was automatically re-added as a member of that group (it appears).

We use this group as a distribution group and also for FS related permissions.

We also have AzureAD but I've checked and it also appears to be remove the user from the group once replicated.

We have no DC's offline, or any that are more than the 60days out of date to cause an issue...

Anyone have any idea on what to check? Where to start?

Comment: [Turn on auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731607(v=WS.10).aspx). Then check the event viewer when it happens again.

Answer (score -2):

I have found the anomaly. Another existing user was re-adding the member to the group. Thanks Gerald, auditing helped track this.